# Gas costs types in Michelson

Tags: michelson, gas, micheline

Gas cost is an important topic in tezos and I would like to understand better

- the different types of it that occur in michelson
- how they are calculated

Could someone offer me a pointer ?

Answer (score 7):

There are eight types of costs:

```
1   Reading cost

2   Deserialization cost

3   Parsing cost

4   Type comparison cost

5   Interpreter cost

6   Unparsing cost

7   Serialization cost

8   Writng cost
```

More documentation is available in this document

https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/blob/e2d3cf9197804a2cfa92715e1a4d640fe5b87af7/docs/gasConsumption.md#data-parsing-parse_data